# How to init an angularjs app from rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

When I was using backbonejs, I used to init the whole app from rails template using some init function.

How can I do it using Angularjs? I haven't found a way to call some init function in a Angular service or some other init function.

What I want to do is give the front end a "user id" if the user has already logged in. I want to pass this "user id" from backend to frontend; and I stored this "user id" using gon gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a constant in the html that is returned from your server. You then inject "pageDefaults" into whatever controller or service that needs to reference them.

```
<script>
    angular.module("myModule")
        .constant('pageDefaults',{
            userName: 'BillyBusiness',
            phone:'5558889999'
        });
    };
</script>
```